# Error C# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WinSCP.Session.Open(WinSCP.SessionOptions)'

Tags: c#

I am getting error in this code
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WinSCP.Session.Open(WinSCP.SessionOptions)'

Can any one please help me out.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        connectToServer();

    }

    private  void connectToServer()
    {
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();        
        sessionOptions.Protocol = Protocol.Sftp;
        sessionOptions.HostName = "server name";
        sessionOptions.UserName = "user name";
        sessionOptions.Password = "pass";
        sessionOptions.PortNumber = 22;
        sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa key";
        Session session = new Session();
        session.SessionLogPath = "your log path";
        Session.Open(sessionOptions);

    }
```

Comment: Remove line `sessionOptions = null;`

Comment: done.still same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error in your last sentence of your connectToserver method,
In your code you have used Session.Open instead of session.Open

Session is class and session is its object so you have to use its object instead of class
Write like below
          session.Open(sessionOptions);